# Image Mapping vs Texturing vs Baking

Tags: texture-baking

What is the difference between Imaging Mapping, texturing and baking?

In sculpting workflow, I have learned that a high-poly mesh needs to re-topologize for avoiding hassle. Then the baking process starts.

My question is:

Do we UV-unwrap high-poly model and bake it to low-poly model that we get after re-topology process?

Is there any good tutorial for these?